# Amazon SimpleDB query through c# not returning any records

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-simpledb

I have built an appender that writes Log4Net logs to a SimpleDB table/domain called LogTable. I am now trying to write a windows service which will delete old records from this table. The AmazonSimpleDB client is definitely being created and the query when run manually does return records. However when the code is executed through a unit test no results are returned. The table and column name case sensitivity are correct.

```
using (AmazonSimpleDB simpleDbClient = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleDBClient(accessKey, secretKey))
                {
                    String selectExpression = String.Format("select * from LogTable where Timestamp < '{0:o}'", purgeDate);
                    SelectRequest selectRequestAction = new SelectRequest().WithSelectExpression(selectExpression);
                    SelectResponse selectResponse = simpleDbClient.Select(selectRequestAction);

                    if (selectResponse.IsSetSelectResult())
                    {
                        BatchDeleteAttributesRequest deleteRequest = new BatchDeleteAttributesRequest().WithDomainName("LogTable");
                        deleteRequest.Item = new List<DeleteableItem>();

                        SelectResult selectResult = selectResponse.SelectResult;
                        foreach (Item item in selectResult.Item)
                        {
                            deleteRequest.Item.Add(new DeleteableItem { ItemName = item.Name });
                        }

                        if (deleteRequest.Item.Count > 0)
                        {
                            simpleDbClient.BatchDeleteAttributes(deleteRequest);
                        }

                        logger.InfoFormat("Success - {0} log records deleted from LogTable", deleteRequest.Item.Count);
                    }
}
```

Would really appreciate some help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only records that satisfy the expression will be returned so please make sure your query is correct. what does a simple select query return? Try this and check -

```
select * from LogTable
```

If you are not getting any hits then please specify the region end point.

and if it returns then please make sure the condition you have specified is getting matched.

**Edited :**

Please try to run this code and specify region end point using this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sdb_region) to which your domain belongs.

```
AmazonSimpleDBConfig theConfig = new AmazonSimpleDBConfig();
theConfig.ServiceURL = myEndpoint;  //where myEndPoint is the region endpoint you are interested in
AmazonSimpleDBClient simpleDbClient= new AmazonSimpleDBClient(myKey, mySecretKey, theConfig);
String selectExpression = "select * from LogTable";
SelectRequest selectRequestAction = new SelectRequest();
selectRequestAction.SelectExpression = selectExpression;
selectRequestAction.NextToken = null;
SelectResponse selectResponse = simpleDbClient.Select(selectRequestAction);
SelectResult selectResult = selectResponse.SelectResult;
List<Item> itemList = selectResult.Item;
```

Comment: No records returned for that query either. I have tried running your query and the one in the code example above through the Amazon Visual Studio plugin and they both return records but the Item count for the code implementation is zero.

Comment: @Cavanman I have edited my post. Can you try a simple program to run simple query and list items?. Please run above program. You may need some changes to compile and run the program. Please let me know the size of list of items.

Comment: Kudos Pancholi. Adding the region sepcific endpoint details resolved the issue. Thanks again...